# I want to remove the "upload image" and "browse image" buttons from the product edit page

Tags: magento, events, magento-1.7, observers

I am trying to add an acl permission to allow/stop a user from add pictures. I have the acl portion working. I just need to know how to remove the buttons from the block.

I have tried this in my observer :

```
// get the block we are working with
$block = $observer->getBlock();

// if the block is null, there is no need to go any further
if( $block === null ) { return $this; }

if( $block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader ) {

    if( ! Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('catalog/products/edit_product_button') ) {
        // I tried this too
        // $block->unsetChildren();

        $block->unsetChild('browse_button');
        $block->unsetChild('upload_button');
        $block->unsetChild('delete_button');
    }

}
```

I have refreshed cache and cache storage and the buttons are still showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which event are you observing?

Comment: `adminhtml_block_html_before`

Comment: Because the buttons are loaded by Flash Object. See `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml`

Comment: Use No Flash Image Uploader

Comment: @dushyant can you explain further how to do this? I understand now that the uploader is a flash object. Is 'no flash image uploader' a different event or something else?

Comment: Install magento dull uploader. Try in searching in google this extension.

Comment: extension causes other conflicts. Is there a way to achieve this programatically?? aka without an extension.